# Does Chilkat MailMan HTTP Proxy support HTTPS?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, http-proxy, chilkat

I am trying to figure out if MailMan `SMTP` through `HTTP` Proxy supports `SSL/TLS`. Till now, I have found nothing indicating a `TLS` support on the official documentation of Chilkat. I am using the `C#` `(.NET)` implementation of Chilkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chilkat supports SSL/TLS over an HTTP proxy.  There is nothing additional you need to do. Chilkat does what is required internally.